# tibble with list columns: Convert to array if possible

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a tibble as follows:

```
uuu <- structure(list(IsCharacter = c("a", "b"),
                      ShouldBeCharacter = list("One", "Another"),
                      IsList = list("Element1", c("Element2", "Element3"))
               ),
           .Names = c("IsCharacter", "ShouldBeCharacter", "IsList"),
            row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
uuu
## A tibble: 2 × 3
#  IsCharacter ShouldBeCharacter    IsList
#        <chr>            <list>    <list>
#1           a         <chr [1]> <chr [1]>
#2           b         <chr [1]> <chr [2]>
```

I would like to convert columns like "ShouldBeCharacter", where all the elements are of the same length and type into a column similar to "IsCharacter", leaving the rest of the columns untouched.

So far I have the following function that solves the problem, but it looks quite hacky to me. I would like to know if there is a better solution I am not considering:

```
lists_to_atomic <- function(data) {
  # Elements of length larger than one should be kept as lists.
  # So we compute the maximum length for each column
  length_column_elements <- apply(data, 2,
                                  function(x) max(sapply(x, function(y) length(y))))
  # to_simplify will contain column names of class list and with all elements of length 1
  to_simplify <- colnames(data)[length_column_elements == 1 & sapply(data, class) == "list"]
  # Do the conversion
  data[,to_simplify] <- tibble::as_tibble(lapply(as.list(data[,to_simplify]), function(x) {do.call(c, x)}))
  return(data)  
}
```

Here is the result I obtain, note how the type of ShouldBeCharacter has changed:

```
lists_to_atomic(uuu)
## A tibble: 2 × 3
#  IsCharacter ShouldBeCharacter    IsList
#        <chr>             <chr>    <list>
#1           a               One <chr [1]>
#2           b           Another <chr [2]>
```

The `as_tibble(lapply(as.list(... do.call(c,...)))` line looks too complex to me but I cannot find a simpler alternative.

Is there any simplification that makes my `lists_to_atomic` function more reliable?

### Update

I did not consider using `tidyr::unnest` on columns of type list and elements of length 1, but following @taavi-p answer I have been able to simplify the function to this:

```
lists_to_atomic <- function(data) {
  # Elements of length larger than one should be kept as lists.
  # So we compute the maximum length for each column
  length_column_elements <- apply(data, 2,
                                  function(x) max(sapply(x, function(y) length(y))))
  # to_simplify will contain column names of class list and with all elements of length 1
  to_simplify <- colnames(data)[length_column_elements == 1 & 
                                vapply(data,
                                       FUN = function(x) "list" %in% class(x),
                                       FUN.VALUE = logical(1))]

  # Do the conversion
  data2 <- tidyr::unnest_(data, unnest_cols = to_simplify)
  data2 <- data2[, colnames(data)] # Preserve original column order
  return(data2)
}
```

Comment: How did you wind up with such a structure to begin with? It might be easier to fix the root problem rather than clean up the mess afterward.

Comment: @MrFlick I have a bunch of text files. Each text file has several "Key: Value" fields, and some of the "Value" are arrays of variable length. If I create a data frame with one row per file, and one column per Key, some columns will be like ShouldBeCharacter and others like IsList. As far as I know there is a bunch of R users that store linear models in dataframe columns, so having arrays did not seem that messy to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
     library(tidyr)
     uuu %>% unnest(ShouldBeCharacter)
```

More examples how to deal with list columns can be found in "R for Data Science": http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html#list-columns-1

Comment: One problem with unnest as it is is that I don't know which columns need conversion in advance. However, I never thought about using unnest with list columns of length 1 until I read your answer, so with your suggestion I have been able to simplify my function a bit!